# BSD has 58 more builtins

Tags: bash

I read the builtins from [bsd builtin(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=builtin&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE) and gnu version from [Ubuntu Manpage: bash-builtins - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man7/bash-builtins.7.html)

```
In [25]: print(bsd_bins)                                                                                          
['!', '%', '.', ':', '@', '{', '}', 'alias', 'alloc', 'bg', 'bind', 'bindkey', 'break', 'breaksw', 'builtins', 'case', 'cd', 'chdir', 'command', 'complete', 'continue', 'default', 'dirs', 'do', 'done', 'echo', 'echotc', 'elif', 'else', 'end', 'endif', 'endsw', 'esac', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'export', 'false', 'fc', 'fg', 'filetest', 'fi', 'for', 'foreach', 'getopts', 'glob', 'goto', 'hash', 'hashstat', 'history', 'hup', 'if', 'jobid', 'jobs', 'kill', 'limit', 'local', 'log', 'login', 'logout', 'ls-F', 'nice', 'nohup', 'notify', 'onintr', 'popd', 'printenv', 'pushd', 'pwd', 'read', 'readonly', 'rehash', 'repeat', 'return', 'sched', 'set', 'setenv', 'settc', 'setty', 'setvar', 'shift', 'source', 'stop', 'suspend', 'switch', 'telltc', 'test', 'then', 'time', 'times', 'trap', 'true', 'type', 'ulimit', 'umask', 'unalias', 'uncomplete', 'unhash', 'unlimit', 'unset', 'unsetenv', 'until', 'wait', 'where', 'which', 'while']

In [26]: print(gnu_bins)                                                                                          
[':', '.', '[', 'alias', 'bg', 'bind', 'break', 'builtin', 'case', 'cd', 'command', 'compgen', 'complete', 'continue', 'declare', 'dirs', 'disown', 'echo', 'enable', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'export', 'fc', 'fg', 'getopts', 'hash', 'help', 'history', 'if', 'jobs', 'kill', 'let', 'local', 'logout', 'popd', 'printf', 'pushd', 'pwd', 'read', 'readonly', 'return', 'set', 'shift', 'shopt', 'source', 'suspend', 'test', 'times', 'trap', 'type', 'typeset', 'ulimit', 'umask', 'unalias', 'unset', 'until', 'wait', 'while']

In [32]: len(set(bsd_bins) - set(gnu_bins))                                                                       
Out[32]: 58

In [28]: print(set(bsd_bins) - set(gnu_bins))                                                                     
{'elif', 'end', 'setenv', 'login', 'nohup', 'done', 'glob', 'notify', 'echotc', 'alloc', 'then', 'which', 'endsw', 'stop', 'switch', 'default', 'builtins', 'false', 'setty', 'printenv', '@', 'uncomplete', 'fi', 'do', 'nice', 'bindkey', 'ls-F', 'unhash', '!', 'unlimit', 'limit', 'foreach', 'hup', 'telltc', 'log', 'where', 'jobid', 'repeat', 'unsetenv', 'chdir', 'settc', 'setvar', '%', 'filetest', 'sched', 'endif', 'goto', 'hashstat', 'rehash', 'breaksw', 'onintr', 'for', '}', '{', 'time', 'true', 'else', 'esac'}
```

BSD has 58 more builtins, what's the cause of the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote from bsd builtins link you referenced:

> Only builtin commands for the csh(1) and sh(1) shells are listed here.

IIRC /bin/sh on FreeBSD is ash. So the page you reference contains built-in commands for two shells. The Ubuntu page you reference contains only one shell's -  bash - built-ins.